# Trying to get JSON data from a PHP file

Tags: php, json

I have a php file that includes this JSON data:

```
<pre>
{
"1": "Select A Message",
"2": "Please Contact (us) Dispatch",
"3": "Send Rate Conf Info (no rates)",
"4": "Pick, Name, Address, Phone, Ref, Date/Time",
"5": "Cons Name, Address, Phone, Ref, Date/Time",
"6": "First sample custom text message",
"7": "Second sample custom text message",
"8": "Third sample custom text message"
 }
 </pre>
```

When I try to access the data from another file, nothing comes thru.

However, when I put the same data above in a .txt file, I can grab it.

BTW, I added the `<pre></pre>` because without it, there are no line breaks in the data; line breaks didn't help tho.

Can JSON data only be contained in .json or .txt files?

=======

ADDED

The JSON data is in a PHP file b/c I'm working with an XMPP-PreBind script written in PHP. That file (prebind.php) gives me three vars that I need. Within prebind.php, the JSON appears this way:

```
{
    "jid" : "<?php echo $sessionInfo['jid']; ?>",
    "sid" : "<?php echo $sessionInfo['sid']; ?>",
    "rid" : "<?php echo $sessionInfo['rid']; ?>"
}
```

The proper values load correctly.

The problem is I can't grab the JSON data.

I tried `$.getJSON('prebind.php', function (data) {`but nothing returns, and no error in the console.

Now I'm trying to use PHP's json_encode and json_decode:

```
$sessionIDs = array("jid" => $sessionInfo['jid'] , "sid" => $sessionInfo['sid'] , "rid" => $sessionInfo['rid']);
json_encode($sessionIDs);
```

Then in the file I want to decode, I have...

```
$sessionIDs = file_get_contents ('prebind.php');
$jsonArray = json_decode ($sessionIDs);
```

The problem with that is that $sessionIDs has all the code in the PHP file, including the JSON!

How can I decode just the part of the file containing the JSON?

Comment: How does the php file "include" the JSON data? Are you actually using the `include()` function? Also, you don't need the pre tags and that is likely causing problems. The whitespace still exists, in html it is just ignored. Also, how is the json generated? And could you show the code from both generating the JSON and including it in php? Thanks.

Comment: there is **nothing wrong** with your 'json' string as in your question, it decodes perfectly into a PHP object when i copied and pasted it and then **json_decode** it. PHP 5.3.18

Comment: I added much more detail to my question, addressing the points raised here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<pre></pre>` tags and use `file_get_contents()` or curl to retrieve the file, no matter what the file extension is. Then `json_decode()` will give you an array.

Example:

```
$json = file_get_contents ("file.json");
$jsonArray = json_decode ($json);

print_r ($jsonArray);
```

Note: I didn't compile it. Make sure your json file contains valid json string.

Comment: I'm trying to use json_encode/json_decode but hit an issue. I added more information to my original post describing the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the string you are trying to parse? Or if you access directly prebind.php what you actually see?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like bad coding style and practice.  You should store the data in a json file, and then have the json data read and displayed in the php file.